# How to get columns from table left join?

Tags: mysql

[**SqlFidle here.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2480c/1)

Mysql query:

```
SELECT 
            n.Type as Type,
            n.UserIdn as UserIdn,
            u.Username as Username,
            n.NewsIdn as NewsIdn,
            n.Header as Header,
            n.Text as Text,
            n.Tags as Tags,
            n.ImageLink as ImageLink,
            n.VideoLink as VideoLink,
            n.DateCreate as DateCreate,
            l.Uplikes as Uplikes,
            ld.DownLikes as DownLikes
        FROM News n 
            left join (Select LikeIdn,NewsIdn,Count(*) as UpLikes FROM Likes WHERE Type='up') as l ON l.NewsIdn=n.NewsIdn
            left join (Select LikeIdn,NewsIdn,Count(*) as DownLikes FROM Likes WHERE Type='down') as ld ON ld.NewsIdn=n.NewsIdn
            left join Users u on u.UserIdn = n.UserIdn
            WHERE (l.Uplikes - ld.DownLikes) < 20 AND DateCreate < STR_TO_DATE('2014-01-01 17:23:41', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
        ORDER BY n.DateCreate Desc LIMIT 0, 10
```

In it query I can't get `l.Uplikes as Uplikes` AND `ld.DownLikes as DownLikes`.

How to get it?

P.S.: if remove row `(l.Uplikes - ld.DownLikes) < 20 AND` result query have 4 rows.

Comment: +1 for providing a SQL Fiddle!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `left outer join` is inserting `NULL` values for `likes` and `dislikes`.  So, use `coalesce()` to convert them to 0s:

```
        WHERE (coalesce(l.Uplikes, 0) - coalesce(ld.DownLikes, 0)) < 20 AND
              DateCreate < STR_TO_DATE('2014-01-01 17:23:41', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
```

By the way, there are many ways to write this query.  Your version, however, is not correct.  You need `group by NewsIdn` in the two subqueries.  Otherwise, you are getting total likes and dislikes overall.  But, two subqueries are also unnecessary.  You can calculate `likes` and `dislikes` in one step rather than two using conditional aggregation:

```
    FROM News n left join
         (Select NewsIdn, sum(Type = 'up') as UpLikes,  sum(Type = 'down') as dislikes
          FROM Likes
          group by NewsIdn
         ) ud
         ON ud.NewsIdn = n.NewsIdn left join
         Users u
         on u.UserIdn = n.UserIdn
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes as you've noticed it's because you use the values of `Uplikes` and `DownLikes` in the where clause, and you don't have corresponding rows in your likes table (so you get null rather than 0).

If you coalesce with 0 in both your where clause (and I guess in your select) you get those four results you mentioned returned:

```
SELECT 
        n.Type as Type,
        n.UserIdn as UserIdn,
        u.Username as Username,
        n.NewsIdn as NewsIdn,
        n.Header as Header,
        n.Text as Text,
        n.Tags as Tags,
        n.ImageLink as ImageLink,
        n.VideoLink as VideoLink,
        n.DateCreate as DateCreate,
        COALESCE(l.Uplikes,0) as Uplikes,
        COALESCE(ld.DownLikes,0) as DownLikes
    FROM News n 
        left join (Select LikeIdn,NewsIdn,Count(*) as UpLikes FROM Likes WHERE Type='up' Group by NewsIdn) as l ON l.NewsIdn=n.NewsIdn
        left join (Select LikeIdn,NewsIdn,Count(*) as DownLikes FROM Likes WHERE Type='down' Group by NewsIdn) as ld ON ld.NewsIdn=n.NewsIdn
        left join Users u on u.UserIdn = n.UserIdn
        WHERE (COALESCE(l.Uplikes,0) - COALESCE(ld.DownLikes,0) < 20) AND DateCreate < STR_TO_DATE('2014-01-01 17:23:41', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
    ORDER BY n.DateCreate Desc LIMIT 0, 10
```

Or if it's easier:

[Sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2480c/17)

**Edit:** +1 to Gordon Linoff for noticing the missing grouping in the subqueries - updated this answer to reflect that.